# How would I set up a swipe gesture that moves the keyboard curser?

Tags: swift

I am currently making an iOS keyboard extension. Right now I am trying to set it up so that when I swipe on the space bar the cursor moves but I am having some trouble. Ideally when swiping to the left the cursor will go to the left and the opposite for right. When swiping the cursor speed should be proportional to the swipe speed(Fast swipe means fast cursor movement).

I know what the code to move the cursor is:

adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset(x)

Where when x is positive it move forward x characters and when its negative it moves backwards x characters.

I have tried to use pan gesture and long hold gesture recognizers but I can not get it to give the right behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using a pan gesture recognizer and comparing it to the last x value the pan gesture returned.

```
@IBAction func spacePanGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view) //Get translation
        if Int(translation.x) > swipeLastTouchX { 
            //If the new translation is higher than the last, move the cursor
            proxy.adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset(user.swipeSensitivity.rawValue)
        } else if Int(translation.x) <= swipeLastTouchX {
            proxy.adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset(-user.swipeSensitivity.rawValue)
        }
        swipeLastTouchX = Int(translation.x)
}
```